# How to set up google analytics with custom campaign attribution (not urls)

Tags: android, google-analytics, nfc

I am trying to set up my google analytics on my android app with "campaign attribution". Basically I have various nfc tags that launch my app and each has an extra NDEF message on them with the "campaign ID". And I want each tag to be attributed to a separate campaign in my analytics account. However the strings are already being passed in correctly from the tags, and this part is working. Now I need to send them as part of the tracker.

I have a seperate MyApplication.java (copied directly from google's dev site) file with:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXX-X";
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER,
        GLOBAL_TRACKER,
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER,      //I don't really need this

    }
    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                    : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
```

}
this is pretty much straight from the google developers site on analytics sdk4

Then in my cameraActivity where I want the custom campaign parameter to be tracked, I have

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements PictureCallback {

    String campaignID = "Tag_1";    //in reality this is passed in from the tag. but i hard-coded it here for simplicity
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Tracker t = ((com.snappiesticker.app) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().set("tag",campaignID).build());
    }
}
```

right now it is having issues with the app's name: com.snappiesticker.app and also with getActivty(). The name is my app's package name. Should it be something else? Also it can't find where getActivity() is defined. However again, this is basically copied directly from the google dev website.

How can I send this tracker correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have setup your Application class (`MyApplication`) in your app manifest with something like this:

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication" ...>
```

Moreover, I assume that both, the `MyApplication` class and the `CameraActivity` class, reside in the same package (your application package `com.snappiesticker.app`). Otherwise package-level visibility method `getTracker()`. If that's not the case, you would need to change the visibility to public:

```
public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
```

In order to get an instance of your Application class from an activity within your app, you would call the `getApplication()` method of that activity. You would then cast the Application object into an instance of your `MyApplication` class. Then you will be able to access the `getTracker()` method.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements PictureCallback {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Tracker t = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().set("tag",campaignID).build());
    }
}
```

Note that you will only need a tracker XML file (e.g. `global_tracker.xml`) if you want to instantiate a tracker from an XML file by using

```
Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
```

If you only instantiate trackers from a PROPERTY_ID string value, there's no need for such an XML file.

Comment: as you can see, I have updated my question in accordance with your advice. I would like one more clarification regarding the configuration xml files. If I am only using APP_TRACKER, do I need to have a configuration xml file? Or is what I have above enough? Should what I have above (in the question) work now? thanks

Comment: @BigBoy1337 Note that there should already be an `<application>` section in your AndroidManifest.xml that contains all your app components (activities, services, etc.). *Do not add* another `<application>` section but add the `android:name=".MyApplication"` parameter to the existing one.

Comment: @BigBoy1337 You only need a tracker XML file if you want to instantiate trackers based on one. As you only create a tracker from `PROPERTY_ID`, there's no need for a tracker XML file in your case.

Comment: @BigBoy1337 Editing the code in your question (to reflect the suggestions from my answer) essentially made my answer irrelevant as the question no longer reflects your initial problem (that I tried to solve with my answer).

Comment: I see. Do you wish me to change it back? Also, is it correct? And I did not create an additional application tag but added to the existing one.

Comment: The code looks good. It would make sense to change back the code of the `CameraActivity`, the reference to the original example from Google and the original problem description (that you had below the code of the `CameraActivity`). The rest is fine as it is.

Comment: I have changed it back. and for anyone reading this unwieldy comment string, the question is now the original way it was